# Twitter Tweet Delete Using "Codebird"

Tags: php, twitter

```
$screen_name = 'demo'; $oauth_token = 'xxxxxxxx'; $oauth_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken($oauth_token, $oauth_secret);
```

How to DELETE My Tweet using this class "Codebird"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We can Delete Twitter Tweet Using Codebird library:

```
$reply = $cb->statuses_destroy_ID([
             'id' => 'TWEET_ID'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a general way how Twitter’s API methods map to Codebird function calls. The general rules are:

1. For each slash in a Twitter API method, use an underscore in the Codebird function.

   Example: `statuses/update` maps to `Codebird::statuses_update()`.
2. For each underscore in a Twitter API method, use camelCase in the Codebird function.

   Example: `statuses/home_timeline` maps to `Codebird::statuses_homeTimeline()`.
3. For each parameter template in method, use UPPERCASE in the Codebird function.
   Also don’t forget to include the parameter in your parameter list.

   Examples:

   - `statuses/delete/:id` maps to `Codebird::statuses_delete_ID('id=12345')`.
   - `users/profile_image/:screen_name` maps to
     `Codebird::users_profileImage_SCREEN_NAME('screen_name=jublonet')`.